# Active Directory concurrent password policies

Tags: active-directory, passwords

I have an interesting problem for you.

Do you know of any method to set 2 concurrent password policies in AD ?

Here is the idea :

- Policy 1 : if password length between 8 and 14 char --> impose complexity rule
- Policy 2 : if password length greater than 14 char --> no complexity rule

As far as I know, by default, Windows will execute the policies sequentially.
Meaning, by default, Windows will override the first policy with the second, which is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have separate password policies the way you described (or the way I understood your question):

> There can be only one password policy if you use the password policy settings in a GPO.

[Microsoft password policies: GPO-based vs. fine-grained policies](https://blogs.manageengine.com/corporate/general/2017/01/13/microsoft-password-policies-gpo-based-vs-fine-grained-policies.html)

Your best bet would be using Fine-Grained Password Policies, where you can specify different password requirements for specified users or groups:

[AD DS: Fine-Grained Password Policies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(v=ws.10).aspx)

[AD DS Fine-Grained Password - Step-by-Step Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx)